# inline div element alignment

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue properly aligning a div element.

For example: at my site:
http://www.journeywithandrew.com/messel-pit-fossil-site-unesco-site/

you can see there is an intro, and then a 'key facts' box.

What I want is for that 'key facts' box to be brought up. So the last line in the box is inline with the last line of the intro text. And of course for the intro text to wrap around the 'key facts' box. So really what I want is to bottom-right align that box. Hope this makes sense..

Tried to make a negative top margin on the 'key facts' box but that doesn't displace the intro text. Just makes it overlay the text.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/76aaT/) will help you figure out where to put the box.

(Trial and error)

Depending on the width of the page-wrap or screen, the text position might change.

CSS

```
.page-wrap {
    width: 600px;
}
.spacerdiv {
    height: 100px;
}
.stuff {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following general format:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>Some words</p>
     <div class="keyfactsunescowrapper">
          <!-- This block -->
     </div>
</div>
```

The paragraph tag, being a block level element, pushes the next content to a new line. The float respects that and does not push itself up.

However, you can put the Key facts block before the paragraph(s) and problem solved. Since it is floated right, it allows the paragraph to flow on the same line and the paragraph won't push it to a new line since the paragraph is after it.

```
<div class="entry-content">
     <div class="keyfactsunescowrapper">
          <!-- This block -->
     </div>
    <p>Some words</p>
</div>
```